# Is it possible to create a class that inherits from the canvas image object?

Tags: python, tkinter

According to [these docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_image.html), the `canvas.create_image()` returns an image object for that canvas. Is there any way to inherit from this image object to create a class?

To further elaborate, I'm trying to create a `Tile` class. Each object of this class will exist on a Canvas and make a grid. The reason I'm trying to make a separate object for each tile of the grid is because each tile will hold a varying amount of information (what is on the tile, for example, is constantly changing). Therefore, I wanted to basically make a canvas image that held extra information, and I thought that the best way to do this was through inheriting from the canvas Image class.

Alternatively, I could just make a `Tile` class and create an attribute in this class that holds the ID to some canvas image, but I thought it would be more clean if I could directly inherit from the canvas image class specified in the docs. Is this possible?

Comment: that is a function, you can't inherit from it (as far as I know at least), simply create an attribute like `self.image = self.canvas.create_image(...)` or sth like this

Comment: @Matiiss ah alright, thanks.

Comment: @Carcigenicate haha seems too advanced for me, I'll stick to just creating a new attribute.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Please note that `.create_image` returns a regular python integer as an id for the underlying image in the tcl world. `tkinter` is a wrapper over `tcl`. Also I don't know any library that discourages subclassing it's classes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: _"You could, ..."_ - no, you can't. The canvas objects aren't python objects or based on python classes, or even written in python. They are objects that exist in the C code used to implement the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to these docs, the canvas.create_image() returns an image object for that canvas. Is there any way to inherit from this image object to create a class?

No, there is not. Canvas objects aren't python objects and thus can't be inherited from. Canvas objects exist only in the internal data structures of the canvas.